# VSCode extension cannot find module when installed from Marketplace

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, node-modules, package.json, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to write a VS Code Extension that `require`s other node modules. Unfortunately the modules are not found when a user installs the extensions from the marketplace.

What I did is add the modules to the `dependencies` section of [my `package.json`](https://github.com/lalten/vscode-unify/blob/1547da5c4bca40d1547e1eddaf8b4bb0fe3315cb/package.json#L84) (Which is what the [extension manifest](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/extension-manifest) wants). When I run `npm install` locally, a `node_modules` folder is created and contains the modules. Running the extension locally via launch.json works.

However when the extension is installed through the [VS Code Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lalten.vscode-unify), triggering its action will fail and the debug tools console will show the message

```
Activating extension 'lalten.vscode-unify' failed: Cannot find module 'tempy'
Require stack:
- /home/laurenz/.vscode-server/extensions/lalten.vscode-unify-0.2.2/out/extension.js
- /home/laurenz/.vscode-server/bin/3c4e3df9e89829dce27b7b5c24508306b151f30d/out/vs/loader.js
- /home/laurenz/.vscode-server/bin/3c4e3df9e89829dce27b7b5c24508306b151f30d/out/bootstrap-amd.js
- /home/laurenz/.vscode-server/bin/3c4e3df9e89829dce27b7b5c24508306b151f30d/out/bootstrap-fork.js.
```

And the node_modules dir is indeed missing:

```
$ ls /home/user/.vscode-server/extensions/lalten.vscode-unify-0.2.2/
icon.png  images  LICENSE.md  out  package.json  README.md
```

(This happens both in a local and ssh-remote vscode-server, `/home/laurenz/.vscode/extensions/lalten.vscode-unify-0.2.2/` also has no node_modules.)

The [.vscodeignore](https://github.com/lalten/vscode-unify/blob/6f81f931ce4e7ee3cb969190ffcae7bd556250f3/.vscodeignore) seems to be innocent and `vsce ls` includes node_modules/.

Other people had this problem in the past, but their resolution was to [update vsce](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-vsce/issues/100) (I have the most recent 1.87.1), using [dependencies instead of devDependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51133944/5559867) (which I do), or [deleting the node_modules folder](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/25014) (which did not help).

I also find it curious that the extension works in [CI](https://github.com/lalten/vscode-unify/actions), so my hunch is that it must be something with how it's published.

Any ideas?

Comment: When downloading the `.vsix` file from the marketplace and opening it as a .zip file, there doesn't seem to be any `node_modules` folder included. So something doesn't add up if `vsce ls` includes it.

Comment: In general, it's best practice to bundle dependencies into one file anyway for improved performance. See also: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/bundling-extension

Comment: locally create a `.vsix` file with `vsce` and determine why it does not include the `node_modules` in that file

Answer (score 3):

It turns out my package.json had in the `scripts` section:

```
    "deploy": "vsce publish --yarn"
```

when it should have been

```
    "deploy": "vsce publish"
```

Now the `node_modules` are included.

Thanks for the helpful comments that brought me on the right track. I will also look into bundling the extension in the future.

Comment: was struggling with the exact same issue for a while, and changing this finally fixed it for me too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, The CI was running the `vsce publish` command and it was set a while ago before I had any external dependencies with `--no-dependencies` flag .

Fixing it was as easy as changing `vsce publish --no-dependencies` to `vsce publish`