# My LSP extension doesn't work when installed from the Marketplace

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I've created a LSP extension for VSCode that doesn't get installed properly from the Marketplace. I found out it doesn't install *some* node_modules (but it installs others).

In case it's needed, the missing modules are:

- vscode-html-languageservice
- vscode-languageserver-textdocument
- vscode-nls
- vscode-uri

This the error I get:

```
Activating extension 'publisher.name' failed: Cannot find module 'vscode-html-languageservice'
Require stack:
c:\Users\****\.vscode\extensions\publisher.name-0.1.0\client\out\extension.js
c:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\loader.js
c:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\bootstrap-amd.js
c:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\bootstrap-fork.js.
```

All other modules (like vscode-languageclient) are correctly installed.

I checked that if I copy those folders manually (or if I run `npm i`), then the extension works.

Also, and even more confusing to me, when I package the extension the .vsix file has all the missing dependencies. And if I install it then the extension works. But when I upload the working .vsix file directly to the [marketplace manager](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/manage) it doesn't work either.

It's like the marketplace deletes those modules for some reason? I didn't find any explanation here or in the docs.

This is my .vscodeignore file (but the same happens even if I leave it blank)

```
.vscode
**/*.ts
**/*.map
out/**
node_modules/**
client/src/**
client/out/**
server/src/**
server/out/**
tsconfig.json
webpack.config.js
.gitignore
```

FYI, the missing modules are inside client/node_modules.

As you can see, I'm using webpack, but if I don't bundle it it's the same.

I've read similar posts here, like this one: [VSCode extension cannot find module when installed from Marketplace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67191722/vscode-extension-cannot-find-module-when-installed-from-marketplace), but those solutions doesn't work for me:

- I just type `vsce publish` in my terminal (the only scripts related are `"vscode:prepublish": "npm run compile", "compile": "tsc -b",`)
- vsce is updated
- Modules are in the package.json file (I even deleted node_modules and reinstalled them)
- Without bundling the .vsix file is 1,62 MB, so it's not a size issue
- `vsce ls` includes the modules

Anyone has any idea what I'm missing?

Thanks.

Edit 1: Downloading the .vsix file from the Marketplace has all the node modules.

Comment: You can download .vsix for each of the extensions uploaded to VS Code Marketplace managed by Microsoft, and then compare to your local copy. That can confirm whether some file contents were removed or not.

Comment: That's a great point. I downloaded it from the Marketplace and opening it with 7z I can see the "missing" modules. So it gets uploaded correctly. Why it's not installing properly then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a solution to my issue, but looks like a caching problem. A workaround I found is to change my extension name. I had no issues after that.

Comment: Answer is not explicit as to what extension you changed and implies that the question is irrelevant and should be withdrawn.  Suggestion is to either provide additional details on how you determined this was a caching issue, if there was something specific about extension name change, or withdraw the question.

Comment: The comment makes me think you didn't read my question and answer. I'm just providing a workaround to my problem in case someone else gets into similar trouble. But if it's better to just delete the post instead of showing a workaround I will gladly delete it.